# Which Url is used for API connection in magento

Tags: api, soap, https, secure, base-url

i am trying to connect `magento api connection using soap client` and  am confusing about what `url use for api connection`.Is `magento used Either used Secure Url Or Unsecure url`.

**My Web Url setting like this:**

```
unsecured is http(http://www.examaple.com/)
and Secured url is HTTPS(https://www.examaple.com/)
```

Then tell **what  protocol is used for api connection?**

Also i want to know  which one is  `proper url for Soap APi Connection`

1. http://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1
2. http://www.example.com/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1
3. http://www.example.com/api/soap/index/?wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried api v2 as described here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: i have already  looked this...  i  am confusing about  secure and Unsecure url which one is used??

Comment: It does not matter in terms of api.

Comment: Amasty. i   have site which is http for unsecure url and https for Secure url... when i am try to connected with https then it show error starting tag missing

Comment: @amsty,have any idea???

Comment: And do you have any errors for http?

Comment: http is response properly

Answer (score 0):

It was `could flare issue setting` .Due to `couldflare issue it is not workin`g.Soap url is

```
working for both https and http
```

Most Case ssl port  is  not configed  properly at server   so it gives that error